# Mongoose: How to group by values and store in separate arrays

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using mongoose to query my video data and this is what I'm getting in response

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "_id": "5f4e1bcc39d8e31964c662b2",
      "is360": false,
      "ratingAllowed": true,
      "commentAllowed": false,
      "keywords": [
        "test",
        "cat",
        "train"
      ],
      "genre": [
        "classical"
      ],
      "similarVideos": [],
      "adultLanguage": false,
      "isDeleted": false,
      "isPublished": true,
      "category": "favouriteinfluncer",
      "influencerId": "5f3b7a7ac1d21a26b808b97c",
      "title": "another test video",
      "description": "Testing testing"
    },
    {
      "_id": "5f4f8d127bc7453654c9b88e",
      "keywords": [
        "ganesh",
        "drawing"
      ],
      "genre": [
        "classical"
      ],
      "similarVideos": [
        "5f4c9522c8d42f0b5a24b9da"
      ],
      "adultLanguage": false,
      "isDeleted": false,
      "isPublished": true,
      "category": "popularvideo",
      "influencerId": "5ee4535219c8037fc3c53959",
      "title": "Drawing",
      "description": " Drawing - Handmade pencil drawing"
    }
    ... array of video objects
  ]
}
```

I want to group my response according to categories like

```
{
    “popularvideo”:[{
        video1data
    }, {
        video2data
    }, and so on],
    “other category”:[{
        video1data
    }, {
        video2data
    }, and so on],
    and so on
}
```

I tried grouping with help of `.aggregate()` and `$group`. I was able to group the response but was not able to get the array of videos for that particular category. How can I the array of video objects according to categories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this way,

- `$group` by `category` and push document in `videos` field
- `$group` by null, create root array, k and v wise, because below we are converting in to key and value
- [$replaceWith](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceWith/) to replace root document after converting [$arrayToObjet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/index.html)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$category",
      videos: { $push: "$$ROOT" }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      videos: {
        $push: {
          k: "$_id",
          v: "$videos"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceWith: { $arrayToObject: "$videos" }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/DsxGsX-Rm3M)

Comment: thanks, this is what I wanted. I'm so noob I didn't know about $replaceWith and $arrayToObject. :D

Comment: added reference link for that, you can learn more about it.

Comment: what if I've a objectID field ```videoId``` inside the videoData? How do I populate it? i tried using $lookup but getting a blank response

Comment: convert that string id to object id using [$toObjectId](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toObjectId/).

Comment: I think I was using ```$lookup``` the wrong way. I was writing the ```$lookup``` after ```$replaceWith``` which was giving me a blank response. But when I wrote it at the beginning it was populating my ObjectId. But thanks for the suggestion. 